# Bind9 (named) does not start after upgrade from 9.16.1 to 9.16.15

Tags: server, dns, libraries, openssl, bind

I am using `bind9` on Ubuntu 21.10. Under an older Version of `bind9`, everything is working fine:

```
$ named -v
BIND 9.16.1-Ubuntu (Stable Release) <id:[censored]>
```

However, when I am upgrading `bind9` to the newer Version `9.16.15-Ubuntu`, I start having problems:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/bind9 status
× named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-10-20 11:03:30 CEST; 5min ago
       Docs: man:named(8)
    Process: 576399 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=127)
        CPU: 15ms

Okt 20 11:03:30 [censored] systemd[1]: named.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Okt 20 11:03:30 [censored] systemd[1]: Stopped BIND Domain Name Server.
Okt 20 11:03:30 [censored] systemd[1]: named.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Okt 20 11:03:30 [censored] systemd[1]: named.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Okt 20 11:03:30 [censored] systemd[1]: Failed to start BIND Domain Name Server.
```

Running plain `named` shows the following error:

```
$ named
named: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdns-9.16.15-Ubuntu.so: undefined symbol: EVP_PKEY_new_raw_public_key
```

This error has no Google results, but the name of the symbol seems to be related to OpenSSL, so I'm including my version:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018)
```

What can I do to fix the problem?

Comment: I already tried upgrading OpenSSL to 3.0.0, however this caused more problems (e.g. curl was not working - `curl: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4: undefined symbol: EVP_PKEY_get_raw_public_key, version OPENSSL_1_1_1`) and did not fix the original issue, so I went back to OpenSSL 1.1.1.

Comment: I think I would report this as a bug. Apparently Bind9 does not work together with OpenSSL. You can report a bug on [this page](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/bind9), but ypu need to create an account first.

Comment: You do not need to create an account to report a bug. https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/report-ubuntu-bug.html.en

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I was able to get the OpenSSL Library to the same version as the rest of OpenSSL by running `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'` and afterwards `sudo ldconfig`. Now, the OpenSSL version is `OpenSSL 1.1.1l  24 Aug 2021` on root and the regular user. However, using sudo still gives the same problem as earlier, I think it the fault of the inconsistence between OpenSSL and the libraries. [I opened this new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370528/different-output-for-ldd-between-sudo-and-root).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was OpenSSL being linked to inconsistent libraries. I had the right libraries installed, but had not removed the wrong libraries yet.

Removing those libraries and running `ldconfig` afterwards solved the problem for me:

```
sudo rm /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
sudo rm /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
sudo ldconfig
```

Thanks to @waltinator and @Tilman for their comments in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370528/different-output-for-ldd-between-sudo-and-root).